# Prevent directory traversal vulnerability in bash script

Tags: bash, directory-traversal

How can I prevent directory traversal attacks in a bash script, where arguments contain directory names?

Example:

```
$STAGE=$1
$APP=$2
deploy.sh dist/ /opt/apps/"$STAGE"/"$APP"
```

The `$STAGE` and `$APP` variables are set from outside. An attacker could change this to an arbitrary path with `".."`.

I know the usual solution is to compare the directory string with the result of a function that returns the absolute path. But I couldn't find a ready solution and don't want to come up with my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#! /bin/bash

STAGE=$1
APP=$2

expectedParentDir="/opt/apps/"

function testDir(){
  arg=$1
  if [[ ! -f $arg ]]
  then
      echo "File $arg does not exist."
      exit 1
  fi
  rpath=$(realpath $arg)
  if [[ $rpath != ${expectedParentDir}* ]]
  then
   echo "Please only reference files under $expectedParentDir directory."   
   exit 2
  fi
}

testDir /opt/apps/"$STAGE"/"$APP"

... deploy ...
```

Example Call

```
test.sh "../../etc/" "passwd"
Please only reference files under /opt/apps/ directory.
------------
test.sh "../../etc/" "secret"
File /opt/apps/../../etc//secret does not exist.
```

1. Test existence of file with `-f` or use `-d` if target must be a directory
2. Use `realpath` to resolve path
3. Use `== ${expectedParentDir}*` to find out if resolved path starts with expected string

Answer (score -1):

The script should be run as a user that only has permissions to access the necessary directories.

Comment: It is. This is just an additional security measure

Comment: it is part of an automatic build setup (CI). The CI-runner user cannot be changed. To avoid vulnerabilities the CI-runner can only run a single deployment script as other user via sudo. (There is a special rule sudo rule for that single script). But we want parameters to control the target directory. And these should not allow directory traversal attacks

Comment: This advice may not be sufficient for preventing directory traversal in general. In a read-only case, there could be plenty of inter sting files readable by the current user.